# what will happens if there is a leak in air conditioning system?

Tags: air-conditioning

In different system such as "Air cycle" and "vapor cycle" air conditioning system.

Comment: This question could be improved by adding more detail. What kind of leak in what part of the system? Why do you want to know? Are you looking for symptoms or a worst case scenario?

Comment: leaks in any part

Comment: Not sure why this is on the aviation SE. But if the leak is in the refrigerant line then refrigerant will leak out of the system leading to reduced system performance and increasing the rate of global warming.

Comment: I think that one is ozone layer no?

Answer (score 1):

In a vapour cycle system, a leak means the refrigerant leaks out, and the result is the same as in a car (because the system is more or less the same).  It loses its cooling ability.

In an air cycle machine system, it depends where the leak is, and how bad it is. Because of the large volumes of air involved, usually duct joint leaks don't cause noticeable performance degradation before the bleed leak warning system detects the problem, the air going through the system being fairly hot up until the final expansion stage in the Air Cycle Machine.

A leak that doesn't get detected by the bleed leak loops, if gets large enough, will eventually get snagged by the flight crew if the crew thinks the A/C performance is unusually poor.